# Intent filter works only once

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have an activity called "MainActivity", this is my main activity which declared in the manifest file as launcher:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.tester.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The VOICE_COMMAND works only one time and then nothing is happen.
I have tried to separate it into 2 activities: 1 activity is the main and the other is associated with the VOICE_COMMAND intent filter, and still, the application works only once.
If it's separated into 2 activities it works fine only when the application starts immediately from the launcher, but if the application starts from the second activity (with the VOICE_COMMAND intent filter) it works only once.
Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: You can try to add from java code also and check.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:
Setting the attribute:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and it works fine.
Thank you